# Ajax POST method data is not send to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the below code.

Why is no data sent?

```
<html> 
<button>Click</button> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("button").click(function() { 
  $.ajax({ 
    data:{ name: "Alisha", city: "USA" }, 
    url:"myurl", 
    type:"POST", 
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType:"json", 
    success: function(){ alert("Hello!"); } 
  }) 
} 
</script> 
</html>
```

Comment: <html>
<button>Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
     data:{
        name: "Alisha",
        city: "USA"
     },
      url:"myurl",
      type:"POST",
      contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(){
        alert("Hello!");
      }
    })
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: what is your error sir?

Comment: This question is highly incomplete, there's no error, we can't magicly know what's going on ?